# Concatenating href strings on javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to link to a website using info windows on [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). I adapted the example as follows:

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">display info</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      'page number '+
      pageno +
      '<p>page , <a href="http://www.myaddress.com/" + String(pageno)>link</a> </p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';
```

The problem is that instead of landing to www.myaddress.com/pageno, the link always sends me to www.myaddress.com

How can I append the pageno correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cut the string, concatenate the pageno, and then pick up the string again:

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">display info</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      'page number '+
      pageno +
      '<p>page , <a href="http://www.myaddress.com/' + pageno + '">link</a> </p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';
```

The `String`-conversion is not needed either, since JavaScript does that internally, much like Java has a `toString()` method on it's classes.